# Laravel 4 nested route and sub urls

Tags: laravel, nested, laravel-routing

I have nested page order,

for example;
URL : /firm/staff

my route is :

```
Route::get('/firm/{any?}', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'StaffController@showStaff'));
```

It is Ok...

On this staff page there is a staff list for example when i click manager...

URL : /firm/staff/manager

```
Route::get('/firm/{any?}', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'StaffController@showStaff'));
```

I used bu it give whooppsss

i searched in google and laravel forums but couldnt,
how can i route this sub pages,
i want to show until 4 level depth.

i tried Route::any but not..

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex with route constraints:

```
Route::get('/firm/{any?}', array(
    'as'   => 'admin',
    'uses' => 'TestController@showStaff'
))->where('any', '(.*)?');
```

Comment: Aykut hocanın sorusuna da cevap verdin ya helal olsun sana :)

Comment: şimdi deniyorum senin kodu :)

Comment: tamam oldu çok teşekk